# How can I pass in specific parameters to mstest in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

I'm trying to modify my test projuect to allow for remote invocation of an api we're building. Right now the tests are hard coded to run locally(against localhost), but I would like to be able to point the tests at any endpoint (even remote ones in production).

Ideally there would be a place in the .testsettings for config values to be stored. Sadly this isn't the case.

Or, being able to pass parameters to MSTest that the test would read...?

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I just created my own settings file, added it to the project with always copy, and knocked up a little class to read it in, and expose the required settings.

It's a  bit naff, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a settings file, like Tony already pointed out, but you also might consider using the concepts of Data Driven Tests as supported by Visual Studio.

I would expect that this technique gives you a bit more flexibility in configuring your tested scenarios.

Here is a MSDN article about it: [How to: Create a Data-Driven Unit Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527.aspx)

The idea of this was, of course, not directly intended to be used for connnection configurations, but you should be able to re-use it with little effort anyway.